# Django - module 'pymysql._auth' has no attribute 'scramble_old_password'

Tags: python, mysql, django, pymysql

I am trying to connect mysql DB in django application. But it is throwing error-
module 'pymysql._auth' has no attribute 'scramble_old_password'.

Comment: Please share your code here.

Comment: see [this issue](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/981).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue:** PyMySQL latest version only supports MySQL version >= 5.6
While in my case MySQL version was 5.5
**Solution:** So I downgraded the version of PyMySQL and everything works fine now.