# module 'pymysql._auth' has no attribute 'scramble_old_password

Tags: python, mysql, url, sqlalchemy, ampersand

I am getting the following error while connecting to database

```
                 url = url.URL(
                 drivername='mysql+pymysql',
                 host='xyz',
                 username='abc',
                 password='xghfh@;',
                 database='abcs')
```

The '@;' at the end of password is converting to %40; How can I avoid the @ getting changed to 40.

```
mysql+pymysql:/abc:xghfh%40;@abcs/xyz
```

engine_sql = create_engine(url)

results = engine_sql.execute(sql_query).fetchall()

```
Version of
```

SQLAlchemy==1.3.11
pymysql==1.0.2
python==3.9

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - module 'pymysql.\_auth' has no attribute 'scramble\_old\_password'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73231565/django-module-pymysql-auth-has-no-attribute-scramble-old-password)

Comment: No, I tried the solution of the above error, but it did not work for me. Thanks.